# Chords formed by intersecting lines through tangent circles

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

The problem below is based on Hartshorne's *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond.*  I request verification, critique, improvement, or feedback on my solution below.

**Problem:** Let two circles $r, s$ be tangent at point $A$.  Draw two lines $EC$ and $DB$ through $A$, such that $E$ is on the top of $r$, $C$ on the bottom of $s$, $D$ on the bottom of $r$, and $B$ on top of $s$.  Show that $BC \parallel DE$.

**Solution:** Draw the tangent line through $A$, labeling the top $P$ and the bottom $Q$.  Observe that $\angle D \cong \angle EAP$, since they both subtend the same arc, and for the same reason, $\angle B \cong \angle CAQ$.  But $\angle EAP$ and $\angle CAQ$ are vertical angles and therefore congruent, so $\angle D \cong \angle B$, and $DE \parallel BC$.

**Discussion:** This result can be generalized to: Given two tangent circles, the chords formed by lines which intersect at the point of tangency are parallel, subtend arcs of equal measure, and, when connected to the point of tangency, form similar triangles.

This generalization suggests an alternate approach, drawing the line $d$ through both centers and $A$ and noting equality of arcs between $E$ and $d$ and between $C$ and $d$.  This approach has an appeal, in that it seems to work with elements more "fundamental" to the result. But I couldn't get it to be as simple as the above.

**Questions:**

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Can it, or its exposition, be improved?
3. Is there a better approach? Thoughts on my alternate approach?
4. Does this generalize in any interesting ways?

Comment: Yes there is a shorter (better ?) approach by using transformation geometry, precisely using homothety with center $A$ and ratio $R_r/R_s$ (ratio of the two radii) [with a negative sign when $r$ and $s$ are externally tangent].

Comment: @JeanMarie Can you elaborate? I understand that homothety preserves parallelism, and if we can exhibit a homothety that maps one chord to the other, we're done.  And, once we've established the chords are parallel and the triangles similar, the homothety you mention maps the figure to itself.  But, without establishing that the chords are parallel, how do we know this? Why isn't this circular reasoning?

Comment: It is a property of homothety that if $P,Q$ have images $P',Q'$ resp. then P',Q' is parallel to $PQ$. I advise you to read the book by Yaglom entitled "Geometric transformations".

Comment: @JeanMarie But how do you know the respective distances from $A$ are in proportion? That is, you haven't shown that the _same_ homothety maps $E$ to $C$ and $D$ to $B$.  You haven't shown their distances from $A$ are in any type of proportion.

Comment: In fact, I consider this figure the other way round. I start from the figure in which $A,B,C$ are known, then I apply homothety, and I build $E,D$ in this way with the preserved property of being top and bottom of new circle r ; this involves in fact the consideration for example of horizontal tangent tangent in $B$ which remains the horizontal tangent in the umage of $B$ (once more by preservation of parallelism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this generalize in any interesting ways?

It generalizes to [Reim's Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/Reim1.shtml), a little known theorem which adds two things to the above:

1. Instead of two circles tangent at $A$ with both lines intersecting, we can have the circles intersect at two points $M, N$, with one line intersecting $M$ and one line intersecting $N$
2. Its converse is also true

While simple, the theorem is applicable to a range of cases whenever two circles intersect:

- ["Reim's theorem... every time you have intersecting circles, you know its there somewhere... e.g. Miquel, Mannheim, spiral similarities etc."](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3103h1114537_imo_2015_problem_3)
- ["The delight of the theorem is in its many converses and special cases, applicable to a wide range of geometric figures"](https://mathsolympian.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/reims-theorem/)